# Facebook Graph API me/friends returns nothing

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

I have an app with Facebook login and the logging in and getting basic profile information works fine. However, when I try to get the Facebook friends (which only returns friends who also use the same app), I get `[object Object]` from the Facebook API. I have the permissions for friends set (according to the Facebook Developer page of my app).

My code looks like this (I'm using the Phonegap plugin, but the code is similar to the JS version for the Facebook API):

```
// Login function (permissions included)
var login = function () {
    if (!window.cordova) {
        var appId = prompt("123456789101112", "");
    }
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email, user_friends"],
        // SUCCESS
        function (response) {
            alert('Login successful!');
        },
        // FAILURE
        function (response) {
            alert('Login failed')
        }
    );
}

// Get the friends
var getFacebookFriends = function() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/friends",
    // FAILURE
    function(response) {
        alert('Retrieving Facebook friends failed');
    },
    // SUCCESS
    function(response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify('Facebook friends: ' + response));
    });
}
```

The alert says `Facebook friends: [object Object]`. I'm sure I have a friend who has also logged in to the app using the same permissions. He doesn't appear on the list, only the empty `[object Object]`. Why do I get this response and not a list of friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It´s not empty, it is a JSON object. You just need to decode it correctly:

```
alert('Facebook friends: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
```

You can also just use `console.log`:

```
console.log(response);
```

Just connect your phone to the computer while your App is running and use `chrome://inspect` to debug it like a website (because that´s what it is).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define a function, you can just do this:

```
function name() {
...
}
```

yes, you can leave that *var* keyword. Also, you should try this:

```
function getFacebookFriends() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me/friends', function(response) {
        if(response.data) {
            $.each(response.data,function(index,friend) {
                alert(friend.name + ' - FB ID:' + friend.id);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Unable to return Facebook friends!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: not sure why you mention the var keyword (it does not really matter in that case), but i would not use jquery for that simple task...

Answer (score -1):

```
I just Hope if this could help you !! 

[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];  in - (void)viewDidLoad Method  

- (IBAction)Loginwithfacebookaction:(id)sender

{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logOut];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

        if (error)
        {

            // There is an error here.

        }
        else
        {
            if(result.token)   // This means if There is current access token.
            {
                // Token created successfully and you are ready to get profile info
                [self Method];
            }
        }
    }];
  }

-(void)Method {

    FBSDKGraphRequest *requestMe = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"/me?fields=first_name, last_name, picture, email" parameters:nil];

    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

    [connection addRequest:requestMe completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        if(result)
        {
            if ([result objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];

            NSLog(@"Email: %@",[result objectForKey:@"email"]);
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:email forKey:@"useremail"];

            }
            if ([result objectForKey:@"first_name"]) {

                NSLog(@"First Name : %@",[result objectForKey:@"first_name"]);
                name = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:name forKey:@"userNameLogin"];
            }
            if ([result objectForKey:@"id"])
            {
            NSLog(@"User id : %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);

            }
                  }


    }];
    [connection start];
}
```